# Changing the Windows 7 login screen background?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen

Is there somewhere within Windows 7 where I can change the lame background image for the login screen?

I know there are a bunch of hacks/utilities/Regedit changes and stuff like that to change it the 'hacker-way', but does Windows 7 not have a built-in way to change this? Or even make it look like the standard windows XP login (ie: user/pass/domain)?

Comment: While I agree that it should be baked in ... What's up with the hacking-hate?

Answer (score 7):

Reading through the search results, they actually do let you without any hacking, but it's still a bit hackerish.
From [this site](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-7-lets-you-change-the-logon-background-image/):

> Use the following Group Policy setting in Windows 7
>
> 1. Start the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
> 2. Go to the following branch:
>    `Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | Logon`
> 3. Set the following option to Enabled
>    `Always use custom logon background`

The next step, it says, is to copy your background into `C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\` as `backgroundDefault.jpg`.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in way is not exposed to users via any nice interface, but it's simple enough to [do it yourself](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/20/bored-with-your-login-hack-it/) -- I wouldn't describe it as a "hacker-way".

If you want the user/pass/domain style, you can get that by enabling the group policy setting for "do not show last username". If you have Windows 7 Pro, Ultimate or Enterprise, you can change it by opening gpedit.msc from the Run box, and navigating to Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options, and finding "Interactive logon: do not display last user name". If you have Windows 7 Home, you will have to change it in the registry by going to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` and changing the value from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there are supposedly "official ways" to change it, but they still require a registry file to be run. There are also miscellaneous programs, hacks, etc. to do it, but [here's a little guide](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-windows-7-logon-screen-easily-without-using-hacks-tools/) they claim is the "official way" to change it:

> 1. Download the registry file from [here](http://windows.intowindows.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/My%20uploaded%20files/Enable%20Logon%20In%20Windows%207.rar). Extract the file and
>      double-click on the file to enable this feature (Alternative method:
>      right-click, select Merge).
> 2. Now, head over to the following folder:
>
>    `C:\Windows\System32\oobe`<sup>†</sup>
>      (“C” is your Windows 7 Installation drive)
> 3. Here, create a new folder named `Info`.  Again, create a new
>      folder inside the `Info` folder and rename it as `backgrounds`.
> 4. Copy your favorite image file to this folder and rename it as
>      `backgroundDefault.jpg`<sup>‡</sup>.  Note that the image
>      must be in JPEG format and the size should be less than 256 KB.
> 5. You are done. Reboot your system and see the change.
>      __________
>      <sup>†</sup> “oobe” stands for “out-of-the-box experience” .
>      <sup>‡</sup> The file name may also be of the form
>      `backgroundDefaultDIMENSIONS.jpg`;
>      e.g., `background960×1280.jpg` or `background1024×1280.jpg`. 
>      The system will look first for the file whose name corresponds
>      to the dimensions of the display; if it doesn't find that,
>      it falls back to the generic `backgroundDefault.jpg` file. 
>      This is mostly useful if you are preparing a distribution
>      that will be installed on multiple platforms
>      (or a live CD or bootable flash drive that will be used on multiple platforms),
>      or if you frequently change monitors, or the resolution on your display.

Answer (score 1):

It is a shame that it isn't a baked in feature of Windows 7.

I use the [Tweaks.com Logon Changer](http://download.cnet.com/Tweaks-com-Logon-Changer/3000-2094_4-10911825.html?tag=mncol) from CNet's download.com.  I like it because it will automatically resize any picture to work for your machine.