# How can I get rid of the Windows 7 login screen background on Samsung Series 7 laptops?

Tags: windows-7

By default on Samsung Series 7 laptops, the Windows 7 login screen background uses the racing image.  According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/180166/windows-7-login-screen-background), custom background is typically set through the Group Policy Editor.  On Series 7 laptops, that policy is not set.

So how can I disable the custom background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom login screen backgrounds are stored at `C:\Windows\system32\oobe\info\backgrounds`

Simply rename the directory to get the default screen.  Open an administrative console and then type:

```
cd C:\Windows\system32\oobe\info
move backgrounds backgrounds.sav
```

Comment: Or you can put your own custom image in the backgrounds folder and delete the OEM one, default size is usually 1024x768

Comment: More info here on allowed sizes of custom images...http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/03/15/windows-7-to-officially-support-logon-ui-background-customization/